# Numpy, Reading from File with no delimiter, and most efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for most efficient way to load file with matrix to numpy array without delimiter.

should I use generator to convert and fill? file consist of single 1 and 0 only

```
000000000
011111111
111000100
110001110
000001100
001000000
110000000
111111100
```

to:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
          ...
]
```

Comment: Do you literally want to read the bytes of the file, or is it a kind of textfile that contains numbers, presumably in rows?

Comment: @mapf just text file,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [numpy.genfromtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```py
import numpy as np

np.genfromtxt('matrix.txt', delimiter=1, dtype=int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
```